# Difference between prototype function and json notation function?

Tags: javascript, json, prototype, javascript-objects, object-literal

I have created below two employee classes, one using a constructor function and the other with JSON notation. In the constructor function, the `print` function is created by prototype so only one copy will be kept and objects (`emp1` and `emp2`) share this `print` function.

**Question:** In the JSON notation (`EmployeeNew`), will the `print` function be held in memory as one copy only? Or will each object keep its own copy? What is the fundamental difference between these two approaches? Which is best for which scenario?

```
var Employee = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Employee.prototype.print = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
}


var emp1 = new Employee("jack"),
    emp2 = new Employee("mark");

emp1.print();
emp2.print();

var EmployeeNew = {
    init: function (name) { this.name = name; },
    print: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

var empNew1 = Object.create(EmployeeNew),
    empNew2 = Object.create(EmployeeNew)

empNew1.init("jack")
empNew1.print();
empNew2.init("jack");
empNew2.print();
```

Comment: JSON doesn't allow `function` syntax. You're using JavaScript object literal notation, not JSON.

Comment: You already wrote the "hard" code. Why don't you create a few objects with different values and see what turns up?

Comment: When you use prototype, all instances will use the same print function. The other way every instance will have it own print function (an copy).

It depends on the usage what method you should use.

Comment: @BenniKa: The second example doesn't clone the `EmployeeNew` object. When you pass an object as the first argument to `Object.create`, that object becomes the `prototype` object of the new object being created, so the two examples are generally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Your two code examples are generally equivalent *(except for some minor details not relevant to the question)*.

This...

```
Object.create(EmployeeNew)
```

...creates a new object with the `EmployeeNew` object as its prototype. So the `print` and `init` functions are shared.

```
console.log(empNew1.init === empNew2.init); // true
console.log(empNew1.print === empNew2.print); // true
```

---

To further illustrate, here's an example that takes the following steps...

1. Create an `EmployeeNew` object to be used by `Object.create`
2. Create 2 unique objects using `Object.create`
3. Verify that the new objects can use the functions provided by `EmployeeNew`
4. Add a new function to `EmployeeNew`
5. See if the objects from step 2 can use that new function

---

***Step 1:** Create an `EmployeeNew` object*

```
var EmployeeNew = {
    init: function (name) { this.name = name; },
    print: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};
```

***Step 2:** Create 2 unique objects using `Object.create`*

```
var empNew1 = Object.create(EmployeeNew),
    empNew2 = Object.create(EmployeeNew)
```

***Step 3:** Verify that the new objects can use the functions provided by `EmployeeNew`*

```
empNew1.init("jack");
empNew1.print();
empNew2.init("jack");
empNew2.print();
```

***Step 4:** Add a new function to `EmployeeNew`*

```
EmployeeNew.foo = function() {
    console.log( 'Foo was invoked' );
};
```

***Step 5:** See if the objects from step 2 can use that new function*

```
empNew1.foo();  // logs 'Foo was invoked'
empNew2.foo();  // logs 'Foo was invoked'
```

---

So you can see that `empNew1` and `empNew2` are able to observe changes to `EmployeeNew`. This is because when we passed `EmployeeNew` as the first argument to `Object.create`, we created a new object with `EmployeeNew` set as the `prototype` of that object.

In simpler terms, when we look up a property, for example on `empNew1`, if `empNew1` doesn't have that property, it *automatically looks to its prototype* to see if the property exists on that object. If so, it uses it.

---

With respect to your comment...

> *"...suppose, if create this.name as property ( name : "") is the name property also will be treated as prototype..."*

Yes, if we do this...

```
EmployeeNew.name = "unknown"
```

...then that property will be shared among all instances that have `EmployeeNew` as their prototype object.

### BUT

Because the `.name` property on the prototype is an immutable *primitive* value *(a string)*, if we try to write to that property, what happens is that the `.name` property is *automatically* added directly to the instance.

Continuing with the example above...

```
EmployeeNew.name = "unknown";
```

Now the previously created instances will reference that property...

```
empNew1.name;  // "unknown"
empNew2.name;  // "unknown"
```

...but now lets update the property on one instance...

```
empNew1.name = "bubba";

empNew1.name;  // "bubba"
empNew2.name;  // "unknown"
```

This is because `empNew1` now has its own `.name` property that references `"bubba"`. This *shadows* the `.name` property on the prototype of `empNew1`, so the search for that property never extends into the prototype object.

Since `empNew2` wasn't assigned a `.name`, it still looks to its prototype for that property.

Comment: So is the print and init functions are treated as prototype functions? suppose, if create this.name as property ( name : "") is the name property also will be treated as prototype (value shared by all objects) i just want to know how do we create prototype and object functions in json notation?

Comment: @user845392: The point is that the same `EmployeeNew` object becomes the prototype object of both instances being created. This means that both instances automatically reference all the properties of the same `EmployeeNew` object, just like when using a constructor in your first example. Try this... after creating your two `empNew` objects, add a new function to the `EmployeeNew` object, then try to use that function on the `empNew` instances. You'll find that it works. This is because the `empNew` instances you created are *(internally)* referencing the same `EmployeeNew` object. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are equivalent, you just need to think what seems more intuitive for your coding style, if creating a new object using *new* and all it's initial parameters, or using an *init* method.

One advantage of the *Class* implementation is that, if you compose your object inside the *Class* definition (I know, it's not prototype-like) you can create inner private attributes, which using just prototype you can't (unless you flag them using a special notation like an underscore prefix). In the end is just a matter of style and what do you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: i couldn't understand fully in your response. Can you give a example for explaining underscore prefix?

Comment: Using pure prototype definition does not allow you to *hide* attributes as private. Instead of that you prefix them with a marker, usually an underscore, to let know that that attribute is not intended to use it as a public attribute, but as a private/internal one. It's just a naming convetion.